# Issues with ambiguous call

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having hard time figuring out what the problem is. I'm trying to make sort of process monitor which loads processes list, ID, username of owner,memory usage and description.. and this error is giving me really big headache.

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] procList = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process process in procList)
    {
        // get status
        string status = (process.Responding == true ? "Responding" : "Not responding");
        // get username and description
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = " + process.Id;
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();
        dynamic response = new ExpandoObject();
        response.Description = "";
        response.Username = "Unknown";
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
        {
            // get username
            string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty };
            int returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
            if (returnValue == 0)
                response.Username = argList[0];
            if (obj["ExecutablePath"] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileVersionInfo info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(obj["ExecutablePath"].ToString());
                    response.Description = info.FileDescription;
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        // get memory usage
        int memsize = 0; // memsize in Megabyte
        PerformanceCounter PC = new PerformanceCounter();
        PC.CategoryName = "Process";
        PC.CounterName = "Working Set - Private";
        PC.InstanceName = process.ProcessName;
        memsize = Convert.ToInt32(PC.NextValue()) / (int)(1024);
        memsize = (memsize / 1024);
        PC.Close();
        PC.Dispose();
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = process.Id.ToString();
        item.SubItems.Add(process.ProcessName);
        item.SubItems.Add(status);
        item.SubItems.Add(response.Username);
        item.SubItems.Add(memsize.ToString() + " MB");
        item.SubItems.Add(response.Description);
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

When i try debugging the program, it outputs few of them without any problem, (see here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufHf9.png) and then error shows up -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi6IC.png

Comment: What is the value of `response.Description` when it works? When it doesn't work?

Comment: try explicitly casting the argument to the add function. `listView1.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item);`

Comment: where are you declaring "listView1" ?

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I suspect the failing line is the line **above** that one (since it involves `dynamic`).

Comment: @averageNewbie I strongly suggest changing `response` to **not** be `dynamic` / `ExpandoObject`. That is likely the root of your issue. By using it you have likely shifted a compile time problem to be a runtime one.

Comment: Ah you're right, I didn't even notice that they had that as dynamic. Then there is really two ways to fix. Either be explicit about the type of response when declaring it, or explicitly cast it when calling the add function

Comment: You also don't need (and it's *dangerous*) `Process[] procList = Process.GetProcesses();`. Just evaluate the results of the `SELECT * FROM Win32_Process` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of both your `response.Username` and `response.Description` is `dynamic`. The `ListViewSubItemCollection.Add()` can't decide [which overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitemcollection.add) to use, therefore, you need to convert them to `string`.

Try the following:

```
string username = Convert.ToString(response.Username);
string description = Convert.ToString(response.Description);

ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = process.Id.ToString();
item.SubItems.Add(process.ProcessName);
item.SubItems.Add(status);
item.SubItems.Add(username);
item.SubItems.Add(memsize.ToString() + " MB");
item.SubItems.Add(description);
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: `as string` may also be worth considering. Or encouraging the removal of `dynamic` altogether.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use `dynamic` in the first place.

Comment: Thank you sir!
Also, any way to make it a bit faster? It takes approx 15 seconds to retrieve whole list in c#, but similar port of this in c++ takes 1-2 seconds at most.

Comment: @averageNewbie Remove the use of `dynamic` to make it slightly faster (albeit not 1-2 seconds).

Comment: @averageNewbie I didn't review your whole code at the beginning. Both mjwills and René are right; you shouldn't be using `dynamic` in the first place. I also don't see any reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

Because you use `dynamic`, method overload resolution is delayed until runtime. You have a `null` `response.Username` or `response.Description`, so the dynamic runtime doesn't know which overload to call. Compare:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic bar = null;

        try
        {
            Foo(bar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void Foo(string f) { }
    private static void Foo(int? o) { }
}
```

This throws the same exception, because both overloads can accept a `null`, and there is no further type information present.

To resolve this, either specify the overload explicitly by casting to string:

```
Foo((string)bar);
```

Or in your case, `SubItems.Add((string)response.Username)`.

Or simply don't use `dynamic` to stuff your variables in, but keep them both declared as separate variables: `string description = "", username = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

The best long term solution is to remove your use of `dynamic` and use an explicit `class` with `Description` and `Username` properties.

The most direct fix is to change:

```
response.Description = info.FileDescription;
```

to:

```
response.Description = info.FileDescription ?? "";
```

Why is that necessary (the `?? ""`)? It will allows the overload resolution to work correctly since `Description` will never be `null`. *The reason why it doesn't work when `null` is that a `null` property of an `ExpandoObject` has no type associated with it. This is different to a normal class whereby the compiler knows that the type of the property is `string`.*